# Default Values filtered in Site.com form element

Tags: site.com

I'm trying to add a fixed default field for account on the form element, and for whatever reason am unable to access the account I need. The list of accounts available are somehow filtered and I can't for the life of me figure out how. I've opened up all access and added account as a partner and still can not  expose the particular account in the picklist. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the record is shared with whomever is viewing the page (i.e., Site Guest User).  It sounds like you may have done that, though. If it is still an issue you could work around it by setting the value in JavaScript.  If you go that route, you can make the maintenance of the value easier by storing the value in a [Custom Property](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_prop_custom_overview.htm&language=en_US).

Comment: Thanks Peter. I combed through all sharing permissions for the site guest user with no luck. Still baffled at how the list is filtered --seems to be no consistency with accessible records. Here was my less than elegant work around: Clone one the accounts that I could access in the dropdown. Rename it to the account I wanted for a fixed value.

Comment: I had an issue a year or two ago, where the default User Id that I wanted for an Owner just wouldn't show up no matter what I did. I ended up having to do the JavaScript workaround, but it was even worse at that time, because there were no custom properties yet.